# Where clause within Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, drilldown

I need to drill into detail on to an existing report which shows me the total profitability per customer, per month on a telecoms company.

The company sells calls, service charges and has discounts.

This is the query that I'm using, using one customer in particular:

```
SELECT 
    custumer_name,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), month_end, 103)
                  WHEN '31/10/2016' 
                     THEN totcall + isnull(totrec, 0) - discount
                     ELSE 0
               END), 0) AS '31/10/2016',
    SUM(totcall) AS 'Total Calls',
    SUM(totrec) AS 'Total Rec',
    SUM(discount) AS 'Discounts'
FROM 
    total_sales
INNER JOIN 
    customer_details ON billingaddress = customer_details .siteid 
INNER JOIN 
    sales_month d ON total_sales.periodid = d.monthid 
INNER JOIN 
    customer b ON customer_details .id = b.id AND b.is_customer = 1 
WHERE 
    b.custumer_name = '2 
GROUP BY 
    b.custumer_name
ORDER BY 
    b.custumer_name ASC
```

This is bringing back the correct total however when I need to show the drilldown of the total on calls, rec & discounts it is showing me the actual sum of every months' data which is stored on that table.

I'm not sure how can I get the last 3 columns to itemise the total without specifying the actual month (as the report has columns for the last 12 months of data.

Please help?

Thank you!

PS. The DB is a SQL Server 2008

Comment: Add sample data in table, current and desired output.

Comment: Are you looking to get the transaction values for call, rec and discount?

Comment: @DarylWenman-Bateson yea. so I want. for example, 3 rows per customer where on each there's a [TOTAL] column and each rows' total will be one for calls, rec and discount.

Comment: the 3 rows being the last 3 months per customer?  or do you mean 3 columns per customer (i.e. Customer_Name, Total_Calls, Total_Rec, Discounts) on a single row?

Comment: Add sample data and the result you want to achieve for that data.